# How to make web.py work with livereload

Tags: python, web.py

I'm using web.py for an app and I'd like to use livereload while being in development but I can't figure out how to make the two get along?

app.py

```
import web
from livereload import Server

urls = (
    '/', 'index'
)

class index:
    def GET(self):
        return "Hello, Kitty"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = web.application(urls, globals()).wsgifunc()
    server = Server(app)
    server.serve()
```

I'm following https://github.com/lepture/python-livereload

> server = Server(app.wsgi_app)
>
> server.serve()

in my terminal I type

```
livereload app.py
```

and I see

> [I 161130 14:05:03 server:283] Serving on http://127.0.0.1:35729
>
> [I 161130 14:05:03 handlers:60] Start watching changes
>
> [I 161130 14:05:03 handlers:62] Start detecting changes

but in the browser when loading http://127.0.0.1:35729 I see this

```
import web
from livereload import Server

urls = (
    '/', 'index'
)

class index:
    def GET(self):
        return "Hello, Pussy"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = web.application(urls, globals()).wsgifunc()
    server = Server(app)
    server.serve()
```

I see the python script rendered as plain tex.

**Update**
I decided to give the whole thing a second try, and succeeded, good for me :)

```
from livereload import Server

import web

from nestpas.views import *
from nestpas.urls import *
import sys

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG)

# web.config.debug = False
web.ctx.debug = False

app = web.application(urls, globals(), autoreload=False)
webapp = app.wsgifunc()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ## app.run()
    server = Server(webapp)
    server.watch('static/', 'templates/', 'nestpas/')
    server.serve(port=8080, host='localhost')
```

The files I'm using are stored in static, templates and nestpas which is where the Python modules are stored. I ran into some issues having sessions stored on disk, but I managed to change that as well by using the DBStore instead

```
from livereload import Server

import web

from nestpas.views import *
from nestpas.urls import *
import sys

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG)

# web.config.debug = False
web.ctx.debug = False

app = web.application(urls, globals(), autoreload=False)
webapp = app.wsgifunc()

# Setup session storage
db = web.database(dbn='sqlite', db='dev.db')
store = web.session.DBStore(db, 'sessions')
session = web.session.Session(app, store)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ## app.run()
    server = Server(webapp)
    server.watch('static/', 'templates/', 'nestpas/')
    server.serve(port=8080, host='localhost')
```

The next goal is to figure out how to use Livereload only when on localhost and not have to think about it when deploying to production.

Comment: Invoking as `python app.py` works a little better for me, as using `livereload` doesn't seem to even call the `Server(app)` code -- you can comment it all out and you'll still get the raw python script. Starting it with `python app.py`, I get the rendered result, "Hello Kitty", but the file gets downloaded, rather than displayed in a browser.... But, maybe that's the first step to a solution?

Comment: And what if you make changes to the app.py? Are those reflected without having to stop and restart the server? That's the main issue I'm facing, I make changes to the app.py file, or rather files inside a module that I then import into app.py and I often have to stop and restart the server to see changes. That makes development pretty time consuming.

Comment: It's not livereload, but `web.py` provides it's own reload (tuned for development). Do `app = web.application(urls, globals(), autoreload=True)`, then `app.run()`. Modules will reload and templates won't be cached, not "live" in the browser line `livereload`: you'll still have to Refresh the browser window, but you'll usually not need to reload the server.

Comment: https://github.com/kristiannissen/jazz-hands/blob/master/app.py I must be doing something wrong. I need sessions while developing but my templates are cached, I get a JS bug that has been fixed

Comment: My mistake: Templates are cached by the renderer, unless you've set `web.ctx.debug = True`, prior to your call to `my_render = web.template.render('templates', base='layout')` (or whatever your equivalent is). So: 1) set autoreload and 2) set debug. Debug also pretty-prints code exceptions back to your browser.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `server.watch` takes a single argument at a time:

    `server.watch('static/')` (newline)
    `server.watch('templates/')`